# Selenium Webdrive Find Element XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to pull the price of the first listing on this website with the following code, but it's returning nothing but blanks. I am navigating to the website, hitting F12, and then copying the XPATH into the line of code below. Any thoughts on why this wouldn't work?

the following gives nothing:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/section[6]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/sup
```

While this shows the listing seller successfully:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/section[6]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div
```

```
driver.get('https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-xs/t-mobile')
pricing = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="listing_previews"]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/sup'))).text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getattribute and switch to the span.

```
pricing = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="listing_previews"]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span')))
print(pricing.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Outputs

```
$379
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting values using `element.text` because span element is hidden by parent tag.

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 hidden-md hidden-lg text-right">                          
    <span class="price"><sup>$</sup>379</span>
                            
</div>
```

Instead of `.text` you need to use `textContent` attribute which retrieves the value from hidden nodes.

Use the following **code** block to retrieve all the products price.

```
driver.get('https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-xs/t-mobile')
allproductdetails=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.listing_row")))

for prod in allproductdetails:
    print(prod.find_element_by_css_selector("div.media-body span.price").get_attribute("textContent"))
```